# Linux Ubuntu how to start standard application scribus from python eclipse anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, ubuntu, scribus

I edited my question, hope it is described better now.

I am working on a software that gives me a nice PDF with lots of matplotlib graphics, depending on the data I get.
So think of a **database of pages**  and then the **software decides which pages are chosen and filled with changed images, The text stays the same.**
So for instance for data1 I get page1-4 and page7 and page 9.  For data2 I get page1-4 and page6. Saved as PDF. I am doing this manually with Quark which needs to be changed. I hope I can figure out the scripting to do so.

**But for starters I cant start scribus from the developing enviroment. Eclipse Anaconda on Ubuntu.**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('scribus')
```

works fine in terminal, but gives me an error in Eclipse which I cant figure out.

File "/home/b256/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.7/site.py", line 178
file=sys.stderr)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This seems to be some Python 2 error in the site.py file

???? Is this some anaconda python path error ??

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me, what you want to achieve, but you're welcome to have a look at a script of mine:

https://github.com/aoloe/scribus-script-repository/blob/master/imposition/imposition.py

This is probably a bit more complex than what you are trying to achieve:

- the script gets started from the terminal,
- if it notices that it has not been started from inside of Scribus (the exception on `import scribus`)...
- ... it starts Scribus with itself as the Script to be run.
- the script runs again, this time from inside of Scribus...
- ... now there is no exception when importing `scribus` and the body of the script runs.

Of course, it's simpler if you start a script that launches Scribus with other scripts.

For you the most important line is probably:

```py
call(['scribus', '-g', '-py', sys.argv[0]] + arguments + ['--', file])
```

It's starting Scribus from Python

- with as little GUI as possible (`-g`) and
- launches the script `sys.argv[0]`
- with a few `arguments` and
- after the `--` tells Scribus what file to open.

Comment: Thank you very much, lots of hints for the scripting to do. I edited my question, it was unclear. Is my tool like some database publishing ? Something like this could be existing already.

Comment: if you load the graphs as bitmap images into your scribus document, then you can simply replace the original image with a new one and use a simple script that launches scribus and creates a new PDF. if you want to insert the graphics as vectors (pdf, svg, eps) you will need to open the scribus file, remove the old drawing, place the new one with the size of the old one (save) and produce a new pdf... not trivial but should be doable.

Comment: Yes, I was planing to just open and close a dokument with new images for the pages 1-4. But can I script to like, throw pages out of a document ?

Comment: In the help you get with F1 in Scribus, in the developer section you can find the developers documentation which describes all Python commands... and, yes, you can add and remove pages through a script.